# autofocus doesn't work when used with ng-include

Tags: angularjs, autofocus, angularjs-ng-include

I want to set focus to one of the input box in partial view 
like  .

and including this by

This is working fine when page loads for the first time. but when I change the partials autofocus doesn't work .

I believe it is because of autofocus work on pageload how can it make work here

Comment: Do your partials have their own controllers? Or they are just markup?

Comment: In my case it only markup

Comment: Did you check the solution that I provided? Any feedback on it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how to fix the problem of page reload but I think we can work out another solution here. I wrote a small directive once to conditionally set focus on an input element.

Here is the code:

```
function SetFocusDirective($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.setFocus);
            scope.$watch(model, function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    element[0].focus();
                }
            });
            element.bind('blur', function () {
                scope.$apply(model.assign(scope, false));
            });
        }
    };
}

SetFocusDirective.$inject = ['$parse'];

app.directive('setFocus', SetFocusDirective);
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="firstName" set-focus="autofocusFirstName">
```

Where `autofocusFirstName` is a `$scope` variable which should have a boolean value.

So every time your partials load, all the directives inside them will get linked and do their jobs. If you end up using this directive, you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Viadik I have not tried this as I am doing the same from controller setting the focus manually still your way is better then mine..