# Focus tabindex on table element in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table with list elements that I want to be able to skip through using arrow keys. Right now I have to click on the table element border before I can use the arrow keys. If I set tabindex on one of the elements in the loop, it doesn't work. So, how can I focus tabindex on a table element when it is clicked?

```
  <section ng-controller="PlaylistCtrl" >
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover " ng-keyup="keyPress($event.keyCode, $index)" tabindex="1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              <button  type="button" ng-click="toSubmit()"  class="btn btn-default">Add resource
              </button>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ui-sortable ng-model="result">
          <tr ng-repeat="resource in result">
            <td ng-class="isSelected(resource)">
              <div ng-click="showResource(resource, $index)">
                {{resource.name}}
              </div>
            </td>
            <td ng-class="isSelected(resource)" style="width: 15px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="sidebarEdit" ng-click="removeResource(resource, $index)"></span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </section>
```

Comment: You will have to focus the element yourself I think. I have done something similar using a directive. Refer to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24590496/1060344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById('table_id').focus();`